# javascript in html spacing

Tags: html, jsp, spacing

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
DynamicImage1(xx) DynamicImage2(yy) DynamicImage3(zz)   
</SCRIPT>
```

This snippet of JS is in my HTML sheet.
(Each function will display a different value based on the input parameter.)

How do I set the spacing between these images? I would like them all on the same row (as they are by default) but with the spacing between.

I am thinking about to put it in a table, but I am not sure if that is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner approach is going to be to separate them:

```
<div id="image1">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
     DynamicImage1(xx)
</SCRIPT>
</div>

<div id="image2">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
     DynamicImage2(xx)
</SCRIPT>
</div>

<div id="image3">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
     DynamicImage3(xx)
</SCRIPT>
</div>
```

Then style them using CSS; use `float:left` to put them in a row and add `padding:right` to space them out.

I said this was the clean way; the less-clean way is to keep what you have but add `document.write("&nbsp;")` in between each image.

Comment: Seriously, there are a lot cleaner ways involving less markup, less CSS, and more code reuse.

Comment: For example, set `img.foo { display: block; float: left; padding-right: 10px; }` rather than wrapping them in divs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing code directly on page, create common container (say, < div id="images_container" >< / div >) with unique id and write images HTML one by one into this container using [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_anchor_innerhtml.asp) property.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Don't use inline scripts where you avoid them, and don't use innerHTML when direct DOM creation and insertion is available. And use CSS to handle the positionin/spacin aspect. Images already display inline, so wrapping divs around them individually is just complicating things.

Without knowing what your method does, I'm guessing, but this is what you should be doing roughly:

```
<head>
    <script>
    function createImage(t,params)
    {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      /* season img to taste (e.g. img.src = params.source? */
      t.appendChild(img);
    }

    /* bind this method to onload event or better a ready event */
    function exec()
    {
      var t = document.getElementByid('target');
      createImage(t,xx);
      createImage(t,yy);
      createImage(t,zz);
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    /* I'm not advocating px here and these are just example values */
    #target {width: 600px; text-align: center;}
    #target img {border: 0px; margin: 0 10px; } /* the margin handles the spacing */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

[JS DOM methods reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml)

---

Why is innerHTML bad? Whilst it's true it can be faster, it's not *always* true, and [it's close](http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2008/04/19/innerhtml-versus-the-dom-cant-we-all-just-get-along) anyway, but then speed isn't really the problem with JS. However innerHTML:

- opens up an injection attack
- can create memory leaks when it destroys pre-existing elements with event handlers
- being string based is error prone
- doesn't return a reference to what you just inserted, and can't clone

Comment: "don't use innerHTML when direct DOM creation and insertion is available" — Unless speed becomes an issue. innerHTML is still much, much faster than DOM calls in most browsers.

Comment: answered in the edit - as always benchmark where it matters, and everything has an application sometimes